# System.Windows.Window.Activate() cannot implement Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Window.Activate() because it does not have the matching return type?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, office-interop

//Error occurred at line 1:cannot implement'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Window.Activate()' //because it does not have the matching return type of 'void'.
//Someone help me fix this error

```
public partial class Window1 : Window 
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSelectWord_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize an OpenFileDialog 
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();


        // Set filter and RestoreDirectory 
        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Word documents(*.doc;*.docx)|*.doc;*.docx";


        bool? result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == true)
        {
            if (openFileDialog.FileName.Length > 0)
            {
                txbSelectedWordFile.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: How about some text to explain your problem? What line does not compile?

Comment: public partial class Window1:Window

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be caused by the two namespaces `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` and `System.Windows`. Try the following to help the compiler to choose the correct type:

```
public partial class Window1 : System.Windows.Window
```